# Has the kangaroo's jumping ever been copied in human engineering?

Tags: transportation

The [kangaroo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kangaroo) has incredible jumping abiltiies. Its [Gastrocnemius muscle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gastrocnemius_muscle) is a major part of generating its jumping force. Has any engineer based a design, probably a vehicle, upon the kangaroo's locomotion system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean wether we have similar structure and articulation of bones and muscles, yes we do, as your link indicates. And some of us by training can jump rather high.

It is more than a muscle or a joint and muscles. Each of our species after long period of time has evolved for certain tasks, obviously.

I think a kangaroo jumps by a nerve impulse which once triggered organizes an ordered sequence of muscle contraction and wave of impulse throughout it's entire body, like a set of struts and springs calibrated to achieve a mechanical feat. In fact all animals do this in sorts for locomotion and doing tasks.

It's in their genes, the path of nerve impulse, the call to instantaneous tightening of back and neck, prohibiting them to lag  limply as a damper, but  work as a wiplash and  and amplifier for the progression of smooth arc of jump.

This is part of the subject of the field of neural networking.

I used to run at my college, and we had learned that you run with your whole body not your legs.